# Как логиниться через cookie/token web automation test

Tags: java, cookie, selenium

Подскажите, как решить проблему. Я использую selenide/Java/TestNG/maven и иногда в форму логин селенид не до конца вводит текст логина или пароля, где-то 50% тестов падают так и на начавшись. 
Испробовала многие варианты, чтобы решить эту проблему, проверку на правильность ввода логина, но нет возможности проверять правильность пароля, использовала JavaScript для ввода логина и пароля, ничего не помогло. Решила попробовать через куки, но не знаю, как правильно все реализовать. Очень нужна помощь. Спасибо за ранее

Comment: покажите ваш код, который не до конце вводит текст в форму

Comment: $(LOGIN).sendValue(“text”);
$(PASSWORD).sendValue(“text”);
$(BTN).click();

Comment: Каждый тест отдельно проходит без проблем, но в самом тест ране, если один тест упал, потом селенид вводит текст в логин не полностью и следующие тесты падают, так и не начавшись :(

Comment: можете ссылку на сайт дать?

Comment: К сожалению, не смогу, это внутреннее приложение

Answer (score 0):

вот еще пара вариантов, что я пробовала:

```
if ($(EMAIL).setValue(LOGIN).getText().equals(LOGIN)) {
        $(PASSWORD).setValue(PSSWD);
        $(SIGN_IN_BUTTON).click();
    }
```

=============================

```
WebElement login = (new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(EMAIL));
login.sendKeys(LOGIN);
WebElement password = (new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(PASSWORD));
password.sendKeys(PSSWD);
WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(SIGN_IN_BUTTON));
button.click();
Selenide.Wait().withTimeout(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если интересует логин через куки то алгоритм действий такой:

1. Получаем токен. Посылаем http запрос на API с локином и паролем.
2. Следущее - переход по ссылке в ваше приложение.
3. После делаете аля:

`Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(ck);`

И перегружаете страницу.

То есть вам надо исследовать API запрос аутентификации. И посмотреть что вашем приложению нужно для авторизации юзера. Например на моём проекте это не только токен, но и еще другие сущности. С этим вопросом лучше подойдти к ответственному за UI и страницу авторизации.

Надеюсь вам помог! :)